# Python: Web Scraping with input from user

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Main_Page'
r = requests.get(url)

Soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
List = Soup.find("div",class_="enws-mainpage-widget-content", id="enws-mainpage-newtexts-content").find_all('a')
ebooks=[]
i=0
for ebook in List:
    x=ebook.get('title')
    for ch in x:
        if(ch==":"):
            x=""
    if x!="":
        ebooks.append(x)
        i=i+1
        
print("Please select a book: ")
inputnumber=0
while inputnumber<len(ebooks):
    print(inputnumber+1, " - ", ebooks[inputnumber])
    inputnumber=inputnumber+1
input=int(input())
selectedbook = Soup.find("href", title=ebooks[input-1])
print(selectedbook)
```

I want to get the href of whichever was selected by user but as output I get: None

Can someone please tell me where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I changed the last two lines of your code, and added these

```
selectedbook = Soup.find("a", title=ebooks[input-1])
print(selectedbook['title'])
print("https://en.wikisource.org/"+selectedbook['href'])
```

This just works !.

NB: The find() method searches for the first tag with the specified name and returns an object of type bs4.element.Tag.

Comment: If this answer is helpful ,please mark it as right answer